Issue with making motors spin in mission planner
I just finished to build my first drone but I can't make the motors spin. when I click on the arm button on mission planner I don't get any errors but the motors don't spin. I have some scratches on my frame that also does PDB but I don't think that they are big enough to damage the circuit. though I have a problem: I can't calibrate the esc's, everytime I launch the calibration, everything goes well, the leds on my pixhawk1 blink blue green,red but they go on forever. I can post pictures if you want but I don't know of what. Any help will be appreciated.
